# /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime

Tags: yaml, bugzilla

While installing bugzilla on RHEL, it checks for required modules:
`./checksetup.pl --check-modules`

It showed some unavailable modules.

While trying to install one of them, I encountered following error:

```
[root@localhost bugzilla-4.2.3]# /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime

Checking for                 CPAN (v1.81)     ok: found v1.94 

**Checking for                 YAML (any)       not found** 

Checking for   ExtUtils-MakeMaker (v6.31)     ok: found v6.55_02 

CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)

CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v5.833)

CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9721)

Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/source/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp19575'. 

Giving up on it. at `/usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225`


Fetching with LWP:

http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz

LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to www.perl.org:80 (Bad hostname 'www.perl.org')]


Trying with "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional" to get "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz" :

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.perl.org'

Function system("/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > /root/.cpan/source/authors/01mailrc.txt.tmp19575")returned status 6 (wstat 1536)

Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/source/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp19575] doesn't exist


Trying with "/usr/bin/wget -O /root/.cpan/source/authors/01mailrc.txt.tmp19575" to get<some URL>

--2012-09-24 17:29:33--  <some URL>

Resolving www.perl.org... failed: Name or service not known.

wget: unable to resolve host address “www.perl.org”

Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O /root/.cpan/source/authors/01mailrc.txt.tmp19575 "some URL ")

returned status 4 (wstat 1024)

Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/source/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp19575] doesn't exist

Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/source/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp19575'. 

Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
```

Can anyone help me out?

thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it cannot resolve hostnames, can you ping www.google.co.uk from that machine?

If thats the problem you can temporary edit your DNS settings, I don't now how it works in Red Hat, but here is the Ubuntu way:

sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

Add DNS server manual:

```
#Google nameserver 1:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
#Google nameserver 2:
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save the file and restart the network interface:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```